# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method _init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads) in_app_purchase

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I get  `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method _init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)` error as soon as I add in_app_purchase as a dependency. Before adding it as a dependency, google_mobile_ads work just fine. I need both in_app_purchase and google_mobile_ads in my app, how do I deal with it?

P.S. Please do not suggest flutter clean and stopping and running the app up again, none of these worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.
I don't know how google_mobile_ads is connected to this, but this error was appearing because I had both [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) and [flutter_billing](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_billing) as a dependency. As soon as I removed flutter_billing, everything worked just fine.